# C#- Embedding source from one project inside another

Tags: c#, pdf, dll

I have a standalone C# application in which I am successfully using MoonPDF (https://github.com/reliak/moonpdf) to display PDF files inside the main window of my application.

I am now trying to add this functionality to another C# application, and have done this by copying the code used in the first application to the second application.

However, although my code compiles, and the application loads and runs correctly, when I try to load a PDF document (File -> Load -> select document) to display it within the window of the second application, I get a runtime error that says:

```
DLLNotFoundException was unhandled
```

It is complaining about one of the DLLs provided by the MoonPDF library.

If I click 'View Detail' on the exception in Visual Studio, the InnerException just says: `null`.

I know that the DLL is there, as I have copied it there, and I can see it when I browse to that location in Windows file explorer.

The function that I am trying to use to open the PDF document is:

```
private void openFileMenuItem_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*Create Open File Dialog */
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog OFDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        /*Set filter for file extension and default file extension */
        OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf"; 
        OFDlg.Filter = "PDF Documents (.pdf | *.pdf";

        /*Display OFDialog by calling ShowDialog method */
        Nullable<bool> result = OFDlg.ShowDialog();

        /*Get the selected filename and display in a text box */
        if(result == true)
        {
            /*Open document */
            string filename = OFDlg.FileName;
            docFP = OFDlg.FileName;

            Console.WriteLine("Panel height: " + PdfPanel.ActualHeight);

            try
            {
                PdfPanel.OpenFile(docFP);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("Document could not be opened: {0}" + ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception happens on the line `PdfPanel.OpenFile(docFP)`, should the DLLs that I have copied over from the first project work directly from the new location, given that I have copied the source code that uses them into the `.cs` files in the second project, or do I need to build the DLLs from within this new location?

**Edit**

I've added a 'watch' to the variable `docFP`, and at the time that the exception is thrown, the 'watch' is stating:

```
error CS0103: The name 'docFP' does not exist in the current context
```

But it clearly does, as I am assigning it a value just outside the `try-catch` where the exception is being thrown... anyone have any suggestions why the compiler thinks that the variable doesn't exist at this point?

**Edit**

I think the error in the edit above may have been because I had forgotten to change the configuration of how I was trying to run the application- it was set to 'Debug' & 'Any CPU'- I have changed this to 'x86', as even though I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows, the DLLs I am trying to use are 32-bit.

However, when I now try running it, I get a `XamlParseException` in `PresentationFramework.dll` which says:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'RiviamAgent.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

The `InnerException` says:

> null

but the `Source` says:

> WebKitBrowser

and the `StackTrace` says that the exception is occurring where I am declaring an instance of the `WebKitBrowser`:

```
WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
```

**Further Edit**

I have surrounded the call to `PdfPanel.OpenFile(docFP);` with a `try-catch` block, and am now getting the following output in the console:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in WebKitBrowser.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' in System.Xaml.dll

Why is it that I'm getting these exceptions in the DLLs, when I've not previously had any trouble with them? How come my application is now complaining about different DLLs to the ones it was previously complaining about? Any ideas how I can resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are working in Visual Studio. In this case you should set the new Reference. In your solutione explorer there should be a "References" menu item. Right click on it and click "Add reference" (or similar). Then you need to click the button "browse" and select the copied DLL file.

Hope I could help. If there are any questions please leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- this was one of the first things I tried, but when I select the DLLs from the location of the project that I've copied them to, a warning message pops up which says: `A reference to "C:\...\libmupdf.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component`.... Clearly the DLLs are accessible/ valid as they work in the other project, and have been copied to the local directory for this project. The location I've copied them to is: `C:\Users\...\bin\x86\Debug`

Comment: I've just tried adding the DLLs to the release folder, and running the application in release instead, and I get a runtime exception that says: `XamlParseException occurred, and the InnerException says: Failed to initialize activation context.`

Comment: It also says: `The invocation of the constructor on type 'RiviamAgent.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception`- I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: It seems that the compiler thinks that the variable `docFP` does not exist at the point that I am trying to open it (see my edit)... why is this?

Comment: If I set breakpoints on each of the lines in the `if` statement in the method that I've pasted into my question, I can see that `docFP` does hold the file that I browsed to, and tried to load using the `OpenFileDialog`. The exception in the console now states `Exception thrown: 'System.DLLNotFoundException' in MoonPdfLib.dll`...